# How to reduce flicker from TImage on TForm

Tags: forms, delphi

I have a Delphi application with a couple of forms. For each form I used a TImage for a background, to give it a different look from the standard form look. The TImage is aligned to the client. The problem I have is that every time I click a button to open a new form, the form flickers. I do create the forms with the

```
frmSomeForm : TmfrSomeForm.create(self);
frmSomeForm.ShowModal;
frmSomeForm.Free;
```

I have tried to use the following code in the onCreate of the forms

```
DoubleBuffered := true;
```

but that does not seem to solve the problem, plus if I do use the dubbelbuffered then it makes my groupboxes that appear on my form to not be transparent. Can anyone please help.

I'm using Delphi XE2

Comment: How about you give up on TImage and paint the background in response to WM_ERASEBACKGROUND? As an aside why don't you use try finally?

Comment: I would typically use the Form's `OnPaint` event instead of intercepting the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message.

Comment: You can always try and set the  ControlStyle = ControlStyle+ [csOpaque] at the Form's **OnPaint** procedure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have no idea on how to do that, how to paint the background onto the form with a image in either jpg or png format

Comment: @Remy That is still susceptible to flicker. Not sure why you wouldn't paint the background in WM_ERASEBACKGROUND. That's what it is for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tile/Center image in the forms background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132326/tile-center-image-in-the-forms-background)

Comment: I would definitely advise you to avoid DoubleBuffered where possible and never to use it on a form.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not even know you can paint an image on a form using the WM_ERASEBACKGROUND. I will start looking into this as the flicker with the TImage makes the application look bad

Comment: Use the code from the near dupe I linked to. It is flicker free.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks David I will try this solution tomorrow morning, it is already late here in South Africa :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the WM_ERASEBKG message and make it do nothing. Below code example should work. Windows fires a WM_ERASEBKG event to the window before WM_PAINT, and the default behaviour is 'clear' the form with clBtnFace (or clWindow depending on Windows version and/or theming). By causing WM_ERAGEBKG to do nothing (in advance of the WM_PAINT) the flicker should be avoided.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
      message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result:=0;
end;
```